# TypeScript returns `":" expected` in Ionic 2 app

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I get a TypeScript error with this code in Angular 2 / Ionic 2:

```
constructor(){...}

    initializeApp() {
        this.platform.ready().then(() => {
        this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition().then((resp) => {
                // resp.coords.latitude
                // resp.coords.longitude
                this.storageService.set("geolocation", {resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude} );
            }).catch((error) => {
              console.log('Error getting location', error);
            });
});
    }
```

error:

```
Typescript Error
':' expected.
src/app/app.component.ts
    // resp.coords.longitude
    this.storageService.set("geolocation", {resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude} );
```

on the "." after "resp".

I am new to TypeScript, should I declare something here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either save your data as an array or as an object:

array

```
[resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude]
```

object

```
{latitude: resp.coords.latitude, longitude: resp.coords.longitude}
```

Comment: Your original code isn't valid JS either, so either you were using a *very* loose interpreter or the structure was different in some way.